# Удаление выделенной строки

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Разрабатываю приложение с помощью WIndows forms и в приложении подключаюсь к базе данных. И мне нужен SQL код, который удаляет все значения выделенной строки в таблице DataGridView и в базе данных

Comment: `if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0]);` этот код удалит выделенную строку полностью. А что такое удалить значения - я не знаю, каждая строка содержит фиксированное количество значений, их не добавить и не удалить.

Comment: @aepot, а этот код удаляет только из DataGridView? или ещё и в базе данных?

Comment: а вы попробуйте, на тестовой таблице само собой. :)

Comment: @aepot если я не ошибаюсь, то этот код удаляет только данные из DataGridView

Comment: Вы уверены, вы проверили?

Comment: @aepot, У меня такая проблема. Я использую Microsoft SQL Server 2019, и подключаюсь к visual studio, и получается что я использую sourceDataGridView(source - название таблицы), и я ввёл ваш код, но он не работает.

Comment: Куда ввели? Что означает "не работает"? Почему вы сразу не указали все технические детали в вопросе?

Comment: @aepot, я создал кнопку и задал действие по нажатию на эту кнопку. И указал этот код if (sourceDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0) sourceDataGridView.Rows.Remove(sourceDataGridView.SelectedRows[0]); И ничего не происходит

Comment: Быть может потому что вы не выделили строку? Кстати, у вас `SelectionMode` - строка или ячейка?

Comment: в конструкторе формы пропишите `dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;` и попробуйте еще раз. Ну или в дизайнере формы можно таблице задать это свойство.

Comment: @aepot, строку я выделил, но он удаляет только из таблицы, а мне надо и из БД, что касается вашей команды, то я не совсем понял где конкретно это писать. (Я новичок в этом, сорян)

Comment: В обработчике `Click` кнопки "Удалить" можно это писать. Почему не удаляет из базы - я не могу подсказать.

Comment: @aepot  есть SQL код который удаляет выделенную строку из БД?